# What is the complexity of the algorithm to calculate power set of a set?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Below is an algorithm to compute the power set of a set. To my understanding, for a set with cardinality `n`, there is a `for` loop iterating `2^(n-1)` times. Hence the time complexity has to be `O(2^n)`.

However, the time complexity as per the solution, is `O(n*2^(n-1))`. What mistake am I making?

```
Arraylist < Arraylist < Integer >> getSubsets(Arraylist < Integer > set, int index) {
    Arraylist < Arraylist < Integer >> allsubsets;
    if (set.size() == index) { //Base case - add empty set
        allsubsets = new Arraylist < Arraylist < Integer >> ();
        allsubsets.add(new Arraylist < Integer > ()); // Empty set
    } else {
        allsubsets = getSubsets(set, index + 1);
        int item = set.get(index);
        Arraylist < Arraylist < Integer >> moresubsets
        new Arraylist < Arraylist < Integer >> ();
        for (Arraylist < Integer > subset: allsubsets) {
            Arraylist < Integer > newsubset = new Arraylist < Integer > ();
            newsubset.addAll(subset); //
            newsubset.add(item);
            moresubsets.add(newsubset);
        }
        allsubsets.addAll(moresubsets);
    }
    return allsubsets;
}
```

The pseudocode looks like:

```
// set: The set[0:n-1] which the power set has to be computed for
set getSubset(set):
    1. set_size = size(set)
    2. set_size == 1:
        2.1 return [{}, set]
    3. power_set_of_subset = getSubset(set[0:set_size-2])
    4. last_element = set[set_size-1]
    5. power_set_of_set = power_sets_of_subset
    6. for subset_of_subset in power_set_of_subset:
        6.1 subset_of_subset.add(last_element)
        6.2 power_set_of_set.add(subset_of_subset)
    7. return power_set_of_set
```

Comment: Can all operations in the loop be assumed to take constant time?

Comment: The total number of elements in all sets together is $n2^{n-1}$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Sure, I get that. But how can we formally analyze algorithm above to get the same?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I came up with a quick pseudocode

Comment: (If you want to use singular in the pseudocode, I'd vote for `powerset` or `getPowerset`.)

Comment: Why not use the base case $0$? Makes the algorithm well-defined for all inputs and less awkward.

Answer (score 3):

The running time of step 6 depends on the size of `subset_of_subset`.

The reason is that the final list needs to contain both the original subset and the subset with `last_element` added to it. This requires copying the subsets, which takes time linear in its size.

Consequently, the running time of the algorithm scales *at least* as the total size of all subsets, which is $n2^{n-1}$.